# C# Console Application WebClient returns "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send"

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, tls1.2, remote-server

I have a console application written on **.NET framework 4.7.2** which is running on Microsoft Windows server **2016** and recently upgraded to a new server **2019**. With the upgrade, my application stops working and throwing an exception "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send". I have researched and used multiple solutions but still always getting the same exception. Have used the security protocol also used **HttpResponse** type instead of using **WebClient**.

```
`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |=  SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`
```

Below is the method I am using in my code: This method uses the Key and secret paraments to access and retrieve a token response from the baseUrl.
`

```
public string GenerateTokenWithKeySecret(string baseUrl, string key, string secret)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |=  SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |
                                                   SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var auth = Base64Encode($"{key}:{secret}");
        webClient.Headers.Add("cache-control", "no-cache");
        webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"BASIC {auth}");
        webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        string response = webClient.UploadString($"{baseUrl}token", 
                                   "grant_type=client_credentials");
        var tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(response);
        return tokenResponse.AccessToken;
      }
      return "";
}
```

`

Below is the screenshot of the exception.
[image]

Please, let me know if you need any more information from me. I would be more happy to make this code work with your valuable suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: The clue is in the error, it says the remote host (server you are trying to communicate with) terminated the connection. Is this a public URL or something on your local network? Are you accessing with the right protocol (https)? Are you using a TLS protocol that the other end supports?

Comment: Do you have access to the other service’s logs to see if your request was received?

Comment: Usually this kind of errors depend on the first phase of the http(s) connection: wrong SSL handshake, server not accepting connections, and so on. Check if the inner exception has its inner exception not null. this kind of exception are like russian dolls. Have you tried simulating the same POST with curl or other tools?

Comment: @ClaudioValerio, I have tried using fiddler or something like an online tool and from there to I am seeing the same error.

Comment: @Virat chances the remote server is actively refusing connection from you (e.g. IP restrictions) or has issues are pretty high. One trick I use to check my code in these cases is to replace the destination url with something I know won't refuse connection, like my company website. Even if I get a 403 or 405 or any other HTTP error is ok. Personally I do not see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @ClaudioValerio, the reason for the issue in my situation is because of the new server box has no ACL open to that destination server, so my org basically using another URL for the specific environments, which resolved my issue. Thank you guys for the help!!

Comment: Ok, thanks for keeping us posted! Maybe answer yourself explaining what was the problem and how you solved specifically, in order to help others in the future :)

Comment: Update: In my scenario, there was an issue with permissions to the server from my application.